# Interpreting SQL Join Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

Im supposed to be converting this query from MYSQL to SQL Server.  However, the join statement is throwing me off.  I haven't seen joins done like this and I am slightly confused on how to translate it.

```
SELECT 
   `Supplier Confirmed Orders` + `Log Tech Confirmed Orders`  AS 'orders confirmed',
   `Orders in CVN`-`Cancelled Orders` AS 'Orders in CVN', 
    tblloadingmonths.`month`, 
    tblvendorindex.`vendorindexid`, 
    'Service' AS category
FROM 
    tblloadingmonths 
JOIN 
    tblvendorindex 
LEFT JOIN 
    tblcvn ON tblloadingmonths.`month` = tblcvn.`month` 
    AND tblvendorindex.vendorindexid = tblcvn.vendorindexid
```

Whats throwing me off is that the loadingmonths and vendorindex tables dont have any common fields, but theyre being joined, and then left joined with cvn.    I've always been taught to do tableA join tableB ON colA = colB join tableC ON colB = colC, but not tableA join talbeB left join tableC ON colA = colC AND colB = colC.  As it stands, the query cant run in SQL Server with the joins the way the way they are.  I had to set it up like this:

```
SELECT 
    CVN.[Supplier Confirmed Orders] + CVN.[Log Tech Confirmed Orders] AS 'orders confirmed', 
    (CVN.[Orders in CVN] - CVN.[Cancelled Orders]) AS 'Orders in CVN', 
    tblloadingmonths.month, 
    tblvendorindex.vendorindexid, 
    'Service' AS category, 
    'CVN Compliance' as metric
FROM 
    cvn 
JOIN 
    tblvendorindex ON tblvendorindex.vendorindexid = CVN.vendorindexid 
INNER JOIN 
    tblloadingmonths ON tblloadingmonths.month = CVN.month
```

Im getting different results for this converted query.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "In MySQL, `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, and `INNER JOIN` are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise." - [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

Comment: Looks like your solution is to cross join the tables without any fields in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taught correctly in that you should list your join clause (`ON...`) and the second query is obviously far more readable and is preferred. Similarly, old-style joins simply list everything in the `WHERE` clause for `INNER JOIN` but again, this is hard to read. Regarding your different results. They are different because

1. `cvn` table name is different from `tblcvn` meaning it's a different object. If that was a type-o then...
2. In the first you `LEFT JOINing` to the `tblloadingmonths` and `tblloadingmonths` tables... meaning the rows must exist in both of those (for your join clause) for `tblcvn` rows to be returned. However, since it's a `LEFT JOIN`, the rows for `tblloadingmonths` and `tblloadingmonths` will be returned regardless of the match in `tblcvn`. In the second, you are using `cvn` as the base table and using `INNER JOIN` throughout. This means that the match must exists for the join clause for the rows in `cvn` to be returned. Otherwise, they would be filtered.

To recap, when using `LEFT JOIN`...

1. The table in the `FROM` clause matters. Swapping it with a `LEFT JOIN` table *could* change the results (as you witnessed)
2. Criteria in a `WHERE` clause could turn the `LEFT` into an `INNER` join.

I can't tell you if MySQL automatically assigns a join based on key assignments, or if it's making a Cartesian product. When using `JOIN` in SQL Server you have to list the `ON` clause. You could use old style joins... `FROM Table1, Table2...` but this should get you as Cartesian without a `WHERE` clause. This should get you close with some edits on your part:

```
SELECT 
    CVN.[Supplier Confirmed Orders] + CVN.[Log Tech Confirmed Orders] AS 'orders confirmed', 
    (CVN.[Orders in CVN] - CVN.[Cancelled Orders]) AS 'Orders in CVN', 
    tblloadingmonths.month, 
    tblvendorindex.vendorindexid, 
    'Service' AS category, 
    'CVN Compliance' as metric
FROM 
    tblvendorindex
INNER JOIN
    tblloadingmonths ON tblvendorindex.??? = tblloadingmonths.???? --find out what the relation is, a foreign key perpahs. Would need a data model to determine. 
LEFT JOIN 
    cvn ON  tblloadingmonths.month = cnv.month 
    AND tblvendorindex.vendorindexid = cvn.vendorindexid
```

Thanks to your comments, you confirmed the MySQL join was producing a Cartesian Product implicitly which you can achieve with a `CROSS JOIN` explicitly in SQL Server, as you answered.

```
SELECT 
    CVN.[Supplier Confirmed Orders] + CVN.[Log Tech Confirmed Orders] AS 'orders confirmed', 
    (CVN.[Orders in CVN] - CVN.[Cancelled Orders]) AS 'Orders in CVN', 
    tblloadingmonths.month, 
    tblvendorindex.vendorindexid, 
    'Service' AS category, 
    'CVN Compliance' as metric
FROM 
     tblvendorindex 
CROSS JOIN tblloadingmonths
LEFT JOIN 
    cvn ON  tblloadingmonths.month = cnv.month 
    AND tblvendorindex.vendorindexid = cvn.vendorindexid
```

Comment: In the first one Im joining tblloadingmonths and tblvendorindex, but I got what you meant.  I was wondering if it was going to left join the join between LM and VI, but theres no like columns in those tables.  Thats where the confusion came from.  Both of them connect to cvn (its tblcvn in MYSQL and just cvn in SQL Server.  Same objects different names) but theyre being joined to each other

Comment: i made an edit @TylerRyanGehring. I'd expect the `tblvendorindex` to be the base table here...

Comment: Got it!  After messing with it for awhile I changed the FROM statement to:

FROM (tblvendorindex cross join tblloadingmonths) left JOIN cvn ON tblvendorindex.vendorindexid = CVN.vendorindexid and tblloadingmonths.month = cvn.month

Comment: That makes sense @TylerRyanGehring and this gives you a Cartesian Product between `tblvendorindex` and `tblloadingmonths` which I guess is what MySQL implicitly did. Glad you figured it out, I updated my answer with your comments. Thanks!